# laravel 5.5: how can I call route in controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

In web.php I have this route which opens a form:

```
$this->namespace('Users')->prefix('users')->group(function (){
    $this->get('/create' , 'UserController@create');
});
```

And this route returns an array of countries. I use that array to fill a select box via ajax in the form.

```
Route::namespace('API')->prefix('api')->group(function () {
    $this->get('/get-country-list', 'LocationsController@index');
});
```

**Controller:**

> app\Http\Controllers\API\LocationsController

```
class LocationsController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
      return DB::table('countries')->pluck("name","id")->all();
  }
  ...
```

> app\Http\Controllers\Users\UserController

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('panel.users.home.create.show');
    }
    ...
```

How can I call `LocationsController@index`  in  `create()` function?
 what is the best method?

Comment: Why not using Model for this?

Answer (score 1):

you can try `return redirect(route('...'));` instead of `return view()` in actions.

**update**

Because you just want to get Countries list instead of redirection. So do small tuning, separate the `data manipulating function` from the `action function`:

```
protected function getCountries() {
   return DB::table('countries')->pluck("name","id")->all();
}

function index(Request $request) {
  return $this->getCountries();
}

function create(Request $request) {
  $countries = $this->getCountries();
  return view('panel.users.home.create.show', compact('countries'));
}
```

Comment: So how can I return `panel.users.home.create.show`? I want something like this: return view('panel.users.home.create.show' , compact('counteris'));

Comment: oh, you actually want to get the list of countries. so let separate the data manipulating function from the `action function` then reuse it inside any `action function` you as you wish

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try a different approach. What you seem to be trying to do is reuse this cumbersome query:

```
DB::table('countries')->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
```

That's good! However your `index()` function is a controller endpoint and which returns a response and isn't really suitable for being reused in other controller endpoints. When I am in a similar situation I usually do one of two things,

#### 1. Extract the code to a protected method and use it in both controller endpoint methods

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->countryNames();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        // $countryNames = $this->countryNames():

        return view('panel.users.home.create.show');
    }

    public function countryNames()
    {
        return DB::table('countries')->pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    }
}
```

#### 2. Create a method on the model, in your case this would involve using the model instead of the `DB` facade.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Country::names();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        // $countryNames = Country::names();

        return view('panel.users.home.create.show');
    }
}
```